# Is possible to put multiple independent legends into Graphics?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, plot-themes

In the following Graphics I'd like put on the left and below another legend where I indicated the scale of the plot: I tried to do this putting into Inset the command PlotLegends->{} but unfortunately this does not work. So if it possible how do the same into others command different from Graphics? So have someone any advice?

### Here the Code

```
 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] = 133320;
Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O] = 9810;
s = LinearSolve[{{1/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 0, 0, 
     0}, {0, 1/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 0, 
     0}, {-(1/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O]), 0, 1/
     Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 
     0}, {0, -(1/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O]), 0, 1/
     Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O]}}, {0, 0, 11, 7}];
a = Extract[s, 1];
b = Extract[s, 2];
c = Extract[s, 3];
d = Extract[s, 4];
\[CapitalAlpha] = {a/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 12};
\[CapitalBeta] = {b/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 8};
\[CapitalGamma] = {c/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 1};
\[CapitalDelta] = {d/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 
   1 + 5*9810/(133320 - 9810)};
\[CapitalOmicron] = {34453/1635, 0};
Graphics[{{Black, HalfLine[{\[CapitalDelta], \[CapitalGamma]}], 
   Line[{\[CapitalDelta], \[CapitalBeta]}], 
   Line[{\[CapitalGamma], \[CapitalAlpha]}]}, {PointSize[0.01], {Red, 
    Point[\[CapitalOmicron]]}, {Green, Point[\[CapitalGamma]]}, {Blue,
     Point[\[CapitalDelta]]}, {RGBColor[1, 1, 0], 
    Point[\[CapitalAlpha]]}, {RGBColor[0, 1, 1], 
    Point[\[CapitalBeta]]}}}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(p\), SubscriptBox[\(\[Gamma]\), \
\(\*SubscriptBox[\(H\), \(2\)] O\)]]\)", "z"}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[PointLegend[{Red, Green, Blue, RGBColor[1, 1, 0], 
     RGBColor[0, 1, 1]}, {"O", "C", "D", "A", "B"}], 
   Scaled[{1, 0.5}]]]
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to put multiple independent legends. Simply put all of them in a list to ``Epilog``, that is: ``Epilog -> {Inset[PointLegend[...]], Inset[PointLegend[...]], Inset[PointLegend[...]]}``.

Comment: I think you may mean `FrameLabel` instead of "legends".  Try adding these options to your `Graphics` command: `Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x scale and units", Bold], 
   Style["y scale and units", Bold]}]`